# Understanding router-outlet

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I want to migrate an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Razor page to an Angular app with ASP.NET Core. Well, I doing it from scratch.

This is the first time I work with Angular and I have created a new app using the *Visual Studio ASP.NET Core Web Application template*, selecting *Angular* option and using C#, ASP.NET Core 2.0, Visual Studio Professional 15.3.5.

Command **ng --version** returns:

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.4
node: 6.11.3
os: win32 x64
```

I have found a tutorial about that template [here](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/04/20/dotnet-new-angular-single-page-application-setup-and-how-the-template-works/) but there is one thing that I don't understand:

There is a home component with a selector called `home` but it is not used in any other component and it is still rendered.

At `app.component.html` I have found this:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <nav-menu></nav-menu>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think that `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is in charge of render `app.component.html` but I'm not sure how it works.

Is it rendering home component because I am at home page (/)? If it is so, how it works if I'm not at home page? With the values at `RouterModule` in `app-module` file?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the tutorial you mention

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
        { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ])
```

the `path: '**'` is the default and will `redirectTo: 'home'`

From the [router docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)

> The ** path in the last route is a wildcard. The router will select
>   this route if the requested URL doesn't match any paths for routes
>   defined earlier in the configuration. This is useful for displaying a
>   "404 - Not Found" page or redirecting to another route.

The tutorial you are that you are looking at is not angularcli, if you run `ng new` with the `--routing` option it will include the routing bits see [stories routing](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-routing)

This will generate `app-routing.module.ts` with no routes, if  you navigate to `localhost:4200/test` it will end up at `localhost:4200` but  you will see errors in your console (so, this is *not* routing it just the way the unhandled exception handling works)

[image: error, could not find any routes. URL segment : 'test']

And now the opinionated bit, I come from an ASP.NET background, I have created a project with the [tutorial](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/04/20/dotnet-new-angular-single-page-application-setup-and-how-the-template-works/) you linked to. It worked, then I had a headache moving to Angular 4. What I do now is.

1. Create a pure Angular app with the CLI in its own folder
2. Create a MVC App for my API
3. Setup a proxy to route /api to your MVC app (FOR DEV)

And to make prod work (you can do this later)

1. Add code to your MVC app to route all not found errors to index.html
2. When you build with `ng --prod build` make it output the files to your `wwwroot` for the MVC app.